# Windows FTP over SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, ftp, sftp

We have quite a lot of scripts that are used to upload and download files with a vendor on the Internet using the Windows supplied `ftp.exe`.  This is proxied via SideWinder and is FTP out to the vendor, however they support SFTP.

We make use of `ftp -s:filename` which *Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the commands will automatically run after FTP starts.*

```
ftp -n -s:dir\filename.ftp proxy.example.com
```

What we would like to do is tunnel this over the Windows supplied `ssh.exe` so that we can eliminate the SideWinder proxy and continue to use the existing `filename` files for the FTP commands.

Is this possible using the Windows supplied `ssh.exe` and `ftp.exe` and what would be the configuration?

I do know that there are SFTP programs out there for free.  We're trying accomplish this with minimal changes to the existing system.  Hopefully it is as simple as an SSH connection in the script prior to the FTP connection and operations.

Comment: the easiest way to do is to tunnel the connection over ssh to the ftp port

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you want, but I strongly recommend switching to SFTP.

First of all, SFTP is a different protocol, it's not just FTP over an SSH tunnel. So proxying ftp.exe over ssh.exe won't work, unless you want to access an FTP server behind an SSH tunnel.

Personally, I'd recommend switching to [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), it's free, [it has a very good Powershell support](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell), so you could easily write a PowerShell script to parse your current file and execute the required commands using WinSCP instead.

Answer (score 5):

[SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) isn't quite the same as just tunneling FTP inside SSH, its actually an *extension* to the SSH protocol.

In *theory*, an FTP connection to a host *could* be tunneled via a separate [SSH tunnel](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example). To do this, you should first establish a tunneled network connection to the server with the `ssh.exe` and then use the existing commands for `ftp.exe` to do your file transfers. 
This would however make the system rather complicated.

I'd recommend using an *SFTP client* instead. This way the secure filetransfer can be done with a single command. The existing text files for FTP commands may require some updating though, as not all FTP commands are the same for SFTP.

There are several 3rd party SFTP clients available and recent Windows versions even have OpenSSH client as an [optional feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse).

If you don't mind using [SSH keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement#user-key-generation) for authentication, I'd just use the built-in **OpenSSH** SFTP client:

```
sftp.exe -b sftp-commands.txt example.com
```

If using SSH keys is not an option, another popular client is **WinSCP**, which also supports password authentication. There is even a [guide](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp) for converting old `ftp.exe` batch commands for WinSCP and SFTP.

Also, even if the vendor's server supports *SFTP* it doesn't necessarily mean that it also supports all *SSH* features. Though SFTP uses SSH as its underlying protocol, many SFTP providers restrict SSH to only SFTP usage due to [security reasons](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/limiting-access-with-sftp-jails-on-debian-and-ubuntu/). This could effectively rule out the use of separate SSH tunneling for FTP.